# Databind one object with another object collection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, design-patterns, data-binding

My motive is to use some kind of Databinding/Datasource (as it is used in DataGridView, ListView by .Net FrameWork) for my own custom object  ***AdvancedTableEntries*** with *`BindingList<Employee>`*

My BindingList Object

```
public class Employee           
        {
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public int PayrollRollNo{get;set;}
        public Address CurrentAddress{{get;set;}}
        }
```

How method GetTableEntries() should be implemented ?

```
class CustomTable : : AdvancedTable
{
 IList<Employee> EmployeeItems;
    public CustomTable(IList<Employee> items)
    {
        EmployeeItems = items;
    }

    public override void CreateDefaultColumns()
    {
    Columns.Add(new AdvancedTableColumn
        {
            Visible = true,
            DataPropertyName = "Name",
            FillWeight = 2,
            Merging = true,
        });

        Columns.Add(new AdvancedTableColumn
        {
            Visible = false,
            HeaderText = Localization.Common.Name,
            DataPropertyName = "PayrollRollNo",
            FillWeight = 2,
            SomeFancyFunction = delegate (object item)
            {
                var item2 = item as Employee;
                return some fancy things...
            }
        });

    }

    public override AdvancedTableEntries GetTableEntries()
    {

    //How to get entries as comparing "DataPropertyName"?and do something like this:

    List<AdvancedTableCell[]> tableEntries.DataSource= EmployeeItems;
    // Or as AdvancedTableEntries 

    }

        }
```

My Custom Object as end result

```
public  class AdvancedTableEntries
{

    public AdvancedTableEntries(List<AdvancedTableColumn> columns, List<AdvancedTableCell[]> tableEntries)
    {
        Columns = columns;
        TableEntries = tableEntries;
        int width = tableEntries.First().Length;
        if (!width.Equals(columns.Count)) throw new System.ArgumentException("Report Entry Column and Datacolumn size doesnot match", "EntriesData");

    }
    public List<AdvancedTableColumn> Columns { get; private set; }       
    public List<AdvancedTableCell[]> TableEntries { get; private set; }      
}
```

> //Expected Table result as :

```
    Name   PayRollNo
    John    12345
    Harry    4567
    Trumph   0000
```